# HoughCircles OpenCV return ndarray into array in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

From houghcircles in opencv, I get an array returned. It's a 2d array with only one column except whwat I get returned is an ndarray. I'm new and learning openCV. The returned array is displayed oddly and I want to sort it by the first column as well as covert it into a regular 2d array.

Array - Not all of the array because its 57 lines but this should be enough. There are no commas anywhere.

```
Circles = 
[[ 876  566    6]

[ 898  574    6]

 [ 846  710    6]

 [ 850  762    7]

 [ 822  574    6]

 [ 880  620    6]

 [ 894  650    6]

 [ 836  604    6]]
```

I've tried using the sorted method for arrays and the ndarray.sort method.

```
sorted(circles, key=lambda circles_entry: circles_entry[1])

circles[0].sort(axis=0)
```

I've used those two methods to attempt to sort. The first one returns an an array with an array of arrays in it. 3D array? and the second one sorts it from all positions.

Examples of first sort-

```
[array([[ 876,  566,    6],
        [ 898,  574,    6],
        [ 846,  710,    6],
        [ 850,  762,    7],])]
```

Example of second sort-

```
[[ 110  542    2]

 [ 332  550    5]

 [ 386  558    5]

 [ 734  566    5]

 [ 744  566    5]

 [ 754  574    5]

 [ 758  574    5]

 [ 762  582    5]

 [ 768  582    5]

 [ 772  588    5]

 [ 778  590    5]]
```

Comment: Most sorts I do also tend to just sort the items in each array itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `circles` is a 2d numpy array.  The display without commas is the normal `str` format of such an array:

```
In [13]: print(circles)                                                                                
[[876 566   6]
 [898 574   6]
 [846 710   6]
 [850 762   7]
 [822 574   6]
 [880 620   6]
 [894 650   6]
 [836 604   6]]
In [14]: circles.shape                                                                                 
Out[14]: (8, 3)
In [15]: type(circles)                                                                                 
Out[15]: numpy.ndarray
In [16]: print(repr(circles))                                                                          
array([[876, 566,   6],
       [898, 574,   6],
       [846, 710,   6],
       [850, 762,   7],
       [822, 574,   6],
       [880, 620,   6],
       [894, 650,   6],
       [836, 604,   6]])
```

I suspect by 'regular 2d array' you mean a list of lists.  At least that's the only array like thing that's standard in Python (unless you import the rarely used `array` module):

```
In [18]: print(circles.tolist())                                                                       
[[876, 566, 6], [898, 574, 6], [846, 710, 6], [850, 762, 7], [822, 574, 6], [880, 620, 6], [894, 650, 6], [836, 604, 6]]
```

One way to sort on the first column, is to us `np.argsort` to get an index:

```
In [25]: idx = np.argsort(circles[:,0])                                                                
In [26]: idx                                                                                           
Out[26]: array([4, 7, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 1])
In [27]: sc = circles[idx,:]                                                                           
In [28]: sc                                                                                            
Out[28]: 
array([[822, 574,   6],
       [836, 604,   6],
       [846, 710,   6],
       [850, 762,   7],
       [876, 566,   6],
       [880, 620,   6],
       [894, 650,   6],
       [898, 574,   6]])
```

Using the Python `sorted`:

```
In [31]: sorted(circles, key=lambda x: x[0])                                                           
Out[31]: 
[array([822, 574,   6]),
 array([836, 604,   6]),
 array([846, 710,   6]),
 array([850, 762,   7]),
 array([876, 566,   6]),
 array([880, 620,   6]),
 array([894, 650,   6]),
 array([898, 574,   6])]
```

or if we first convert `circles` to the nested list:

```
In [32]: sorted(circles.tolist(), key=lambda x: x[0])                                                  
Out[32]: 
[[822, 574, 6],
 [836, 604, 6],
 [846, 710, 6],
 [850, 762, 7],
 [876, 566, 6],
 [880, 620, 6],
 [894, 650, 6],
 [898, 574, 6]]
```

Comment: Ah sorry I wasn't clear. The list portion is correct thanks!. However, when I use the argsort, I get this error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joeyz\Downloads\New folder\Eye.py", line 12, in <module>
    sc = circles[idx,:]
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1